# MUI5 drawer on top of a modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, material-ui, modal-dialog

Using MUI5 I need to open a side drawer on top of a modal dialog that triggers it. Is that possible? Currently, the dialog triggers the side drawer but it opens behind this.

It seems like a modal dialog (drawer) is trying to open over an already-opened modal dialog.

codesandbox example.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dialogwithdrawer-y793fx?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox with what you already have?

Comment: @DerekGlassick It's part of a huge project. I have to rewrite a simpler one. I will do it and I will update my question

Comment: @DerekGlassick Check the code-sandbox example I uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think this is a matter of picking the right `z-index`. I was able to get the drawer to open in front of the modal dialog by adjusting their z-indexes manually. The className you also need to adjust is `MuiDialog-root`. The default z-index for that class is 1300. If you adjust that value to something lower than the drawer then it should work.

Another solution would be to adjust the z-index of the Drawer like:

```js
<Drawer
   anchor={anchor}
   open={state[anchor]}
   onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
   style={{ zIndex: "1399" }}
   >
      {list(anchor)}
</Drawer>
```

That should work too. Here is my [fork](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dialogwithdrawer-forked-lj4nqd?file=%2Fsrc%2Fdrawer.js%3A36%2C71) of your sandbox with the change.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks

Comment: To add that I set the zIndex to 1300 to be able to open TextField Select Menu Items. Otherwise, it would show behind the drawer.

Comment: Yeah, anything that you're wanting to show over one of those elements should have the same, or higher z-index.